# What's the best size for user flair?

Tags: discussion, flair, combined-flair

The [directions for user flair](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/flair) have sample code that uses 208 x 58px as the size for the flair, but at this size the image looks fuzzy, as though it has been scaled from some other size:

[image: user flair]

Is there some optimal "native" size that will produce a sharper image? Or is the fuzziness due to some other factor such as heavy compression?

**If there's an optimal size, what is it?**

Comment: Well, it's not SVG thus when zoomed in it will get blurry - is this what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

The HTML snippet provided is just a link wrapped around an image. The image itself (at https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/323395.png in your case) is indeed a 208 x 58 pixel PNG:

[image: Image info for Caleb's flair]

Here's the image scaled up a bit:

[image: Caleb's flair]

That doesn't look blurry to me – icons etc. are generally sharp, and text just has normal anti-aliasing.